# Error with BiGSCAPE even after installing

Tags: biopython

I am no coding person by any means but I try my best to work with issues. so I had installed BiGSCAPE to look at the secondary metabolites clusters. I am running it in conda and it seems to be installed fine. As it provides me the version number.
However I keep getting this error. I have test it with the example data as well. and it returns the same results/error
The version I have installed is
BiG-SCAPE 1.1.4 (2022-04-14)

(bigscape) Shaheens-MacBook-Pro:BIG-SCAPE shaheenbibi$ python bigscape.py -i /Downloads/gbks  -o ResultsAndres
/Users/shaheenbibi/miniconda3/envs/bigscape/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Bio/SubsMat/**init**.py:131: BiopythonDeprecationWarning: Bio.SubsMat has been deprecated, and we intend to remove it in a future release of Biopython. As an alternative, please consider using Bio.Align.substitution_matrices as a replacement, and contact the Biopython developers if you still need the Bio.SubsMat module.
BiopythonDeprecationWarning,

- - Processing input files - -
    Output folder already exists
    Logs folder already exists
    Cache folder already exists
    BGC fastas folder already exists
    Domtable folder already exists
    Domains folder already exists
    pfs folder already exists
    pfd folder already exists
    Including files with one or more of the following strings in their filename: 'cluster', 'region'
    Skipping files with one or more of the following strings in their filename: 'final'

Importing GenBank files

Starting with 0 files
Files that had its sequence extracted: 0

Creating output directories
SVG folder already exists
Networks folder already exists

Trying threading on 4 cores

Predicting domains using hmmscan
All fasta files had already been processed
Finished generating domtable files.

Parsing hmmscan domtable files
All domtable files had already been processed
Finished generating pfs and pfd files.

Processing domains sequence files
Adding sequences to corresponding domains file
Reading the ordered list of domains from the pfs files
Creating arrower-like figures for each BGC
Parsing hmm file for domain information
Done
All SVG from the input files seem to be in the SVG folder
Finished creating figures

- - Calculating distance matrix - -
    Performing multiple alignment of domain sequences
    No domain fasta files found to align
    Trying to read domain alignments (*.algn files)
    No aligned sequences found in the domain folder (run without the --skip_ma parameter or point to the correct output folder)

Answer (score 0):

`Starting with 0 files Files` seems to indicate that something is wrong with your input directory. You may need to put some .gbk files in `/Downloads/gbks`.

Also note that BiGSCAPE puts a bunch of constraints on the names of the .gbk files: https://git.wageningenur.nl/medema-group/BiG-SCAPE/-/wikis/input. Perhaps your inputs .gbk files need to be renamed.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I do believe its something to do with the input directory. However, I am running it on the sample files they provided for BigSCAPE. also, each gbk file is named like JOBV01000001.1.cluster003.gbk etc

Comment: What is the output from `ls -l /Downloads/gbks/*`?

Comment: You mean whats in the output file after running ??

Comment: Its SVG, cache,logs and network. But all are empty

Comment: If you open a terminal and run the command `ls -l /Downloads/gbks/*` then what gets printed out by that command? If `/Downloads/gbks/` is empty, then that is your problem, as that is where you've told it to find the input files.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. It was not detecting the path. When I wrote the whole path, it worked. I really appreciate your help!!